# Closely related definitions with and without approximation built-in

Tags: real-analysis, lo.logic

Let us say that a (real) function class $A$ has 'approximation built-in' in case for every $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ in $A$ and any $x\in \mathbb{R}$, we can approximate $f(x)$ using only $f(q)$ for all $q\in \mathbb{Q}$.

Examples of such function classes include: continuity, normalised bounded variation, Baire 1, cadlag, and quasi-continuity.

Non-examples include: bounded variation, regulated, cliquish, semi-continuity, Baire 2.

Examples and non-examples of such function classes can be closely related: every cliquish function is the sum of two quasi-continuous ones (on the reals).  Similarly, cadlag and regulated seem fairly close and the same for bounded variation and its normalised restriction.

I am looking for more such pairs of examples and non-examples that are closely related.  More examples of either examples and non-examples are welcome too.

I am also looking for connections to logic, esp. in case the approximation at hand is heavily restricted (say in terms of the background system or computational resources).